# ¿Como evitar que browsersync deje de correr el servidor cuando algo se compila mal?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Tengo en mi gulpfile una gulp task por defecto que ejecuta la funcion server la cual es la que levanta el servidor(uso browsersync) y despues observa cambios en archivos .pug, .styl.
Mi problema es que cuando compilar los archivos pug y styl el servidor se cierra y tengo que volver a ejecutar gulp, mi pregunta es ¿Qué puedo hacer para que cuando algo falle al compilarse no se detenga la funcion server(la cual es de browsersync y la que levanta el servidor)?

```
// INICIAR SERVER
gulp.task('default', () => {
  server()
  // OBSERVAR LOS CAMBIOS DE PUG Y STYLUS
  gulp.watch('dev/**/*.pug').on('change', gulp.series('pug', browserSync.reload))
  gulp.watch('dev/**/*.styl').on('change', gulp.series('stylus', browserSync.reload))
  gulp.watch('dev/theme.styl').on('change', gulp.series('stylus', 'pug', browserSync.reload))
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para recargar el navegador deberias observar unicamente los archivos generados.
Para los estilos creo que no es necesario recargar el navegador solo necesitas la funcion stream.

```
gulp.task('stylus', function() {
    return gulp.src("app/scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(stylus())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', () => {
  server()
  // OBSERVAR LOS CAMBIOS DE PUG Y STYLUS
  gulp.watch('dev/**/*.stylus').on('change', ['stylus'])
  gulp.watch('dev/**/*.pug').on('change', ['pug'])
  gulp.watch('build/**/*.html').on('change', browsersync.reload)
})
```

Creo que de esta manera no te frena el watch. esto pasa porque estas ejecutando 2 acciones en un mismo escuchador.

fijate que tambien la sintaxis nueva utilizada con gulp es con funciones te dejo un repositorio en el que tengo configurado gulp para sass de hace unas semanas. Para stylys es igual.

https://github.com/rubengvillar/challenge-pricing-toggle/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias !, me sirvio mucho el enlace a github que me mandaste :), me ayudo tambien a ver un poco como otras personas organizan su gulpfile